# ANT sql task: How to run SQL and PL/SQL and notice execution failure?

Tags: sql, ant, plsql

to execute an .sql script file from ANT it works fine using the following task:

```
<sql
    classpath="${oracle.jar}" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@@@{db.hostname}:@{db.port}:@{db.sid}" 
    userid="@{db.user}" 
    password="@{db.password}"
    src="@{db.sql.script}" />
```

But if the .sql file not only contains pure SQL but also PL/SQL the task will fail. This could be solved by using the following snippet:

```
<sql
    classpath="${oracle.jar}" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@@@{db.hostname}:@{db.port}:@{db.sid}" 
    userid="@{db.user}" 
    password="@{db.password}"
    delimiter="/"
    delimitertype="row"
    src="@{db.sql.script}" />
```

But if my script contains both SQL **and** PL/SQL then neither ANT task will work. Another solution would be to use the "exec" task with "sqlplus":

```
<exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" errorproperty="exit.status">
    <arg value="${db.user}/${db.password}@${db.hostname}:${db.port}/${db.sid}"/>
    <arg value="@${db.sql.script}"/>
</exec>
```

But unfortunately this task will never fail, hence the build returns always with "SUCCESSFUL" even though the sql script execution failed. The error property which I tried to set would not return any error code.

Any ideas/suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 6):

Peter,

Add at the beginning of scripts

```
  WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.CODE;
```

Then sqlplus will exit with exit code != 0.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty late, I guess - but I hope this will help someone:

In general, I think we should perfer using sql rather than exec executable="sqlplus" for many reasons, such as: in case we change DB provider, you don't spend reaources in a new process with sql, "STOPPING" will work as opposed to sqlplus.exe etc.

Anyway, here's a suggestion on how to let  both PL/SQL & SQL in same script so that it will work:

myScript.sql:

---

```
<copy todir="...">
  <fileset dir="...." includes="myScript.sql"/>
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregex byline="false" pattern=";" replace="{line.separator}/" flags="mg"/>
    <replaceregex byline="false" pattern="/[\s]*/" replace=";${line.separator}/"  flags="mg"/>
   </filterchain>
</copy>
```

then give the result to:
    `<sql delimeter="/" src="myScript.sql"/>`

explaination:
If you have regular sql commands:

```
drop table x;
select blah from blue where bli=blee;
```

They will be transformed to:

```
drop table x
/
select blah from blue where bli=blee
/
```

which is equivlant - and the sql command with "/"     delimeter can handle them.

On the other hand,

```
BEGIN
  blah
END;
/
```

will be transformed to:

```
BEGIN
  blas
END/
/
```

and using the second regex - transformed back to

```
BEGIN
  blas
END;
/
```

So everybody wins! Hurray!

Good luck.

Comment: I tried with replace semicolon with slash and it works fine. However I have a few package create scripts which I have with semi colons. If I replace semi colon with slash ant executes sql scrips successfully but all packages are created with compilation errors due to error `Encountered symbol /` Are there are any ways we could resolve this issue? Thanks