# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol / when execute from ant build

Tags: sql, oracle, ant, plsql, oracle10g

I have sql script which contains package spec and body and each one of them is separated
by `forward slash /` This executes fine when I run from sql plus or Sql Developer.

When I execute from ant build, sql scripts executes fine and build is successful.
However package has errors with `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol /`. My ant build script for sql is as follows

```
<target name="sql">        
      <sql driver="${sql.driver}" url="${sql.url.test}" 
      userid="${sql.user}" password="${databasepassword}" 
      classpathref="antclasspath" keepformat="true" 
      delimitertype="row">
      <transaction src="create.sql"/>          
      </sql>
   </target>
```

How can I resolve this error? Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729033/1083652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set delimitier to "/". You have than to chane your script to end all commands with "/", not only PL/SQL, but it should work.

Comment: You mean to say that I should be using `"/"` instead of `semi colons (;)` as well to terminate a line?

Comment: Right, I don't know ant dB scripts exactly, but it could work